# Is it possible to train a single Keras Model on Two different GPU on two different systems and combine the training?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm using Google Colab for training my models.
But speed is still low.
So is there a way I can train from two different accounts and combine the training later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot train using 2 accounts the same model on colab. Google colab is for research purposes only. Not to train large scale production models. Colab also disconnects the kernel every 12 hour.

---

You can instead train the model using multiple GPU's on a single computer. Keras supports multi GPU training when using tensorflow as backend. But training on two different computers/VM is not possible. How will gradients flow during back propagation?

---

There is a solution though, but not an end-to-end approach. You can split your model into two different models, where the output of first model will become the input for second and second will produce the final output. For this you need a different training set for each model.

Take this example.
Suppose you are building a face recogniser where the model takes in a raw camera picture and recognises the face as yes/no.

Instead of training this big Networks you could split it into two different nets, where task for first net will be to crop the face and remove other useless things from image and second to recognise from cropped image.

This is non end-to-end model, and you can train the two models diffently on different machines with different dataset and then eventually merge it together. This is usually more powerful and easy to train.

Answer (score 0):

Look up this question [Tensorflow Combining Two Models End to End](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895225/tensorflow-combining-two-models-end-to-end)

Another possibility is to ensemble the two trained models. You'd have to make sure however that the data for both of the models are coming from the same distribution.